# Disabling bwshare in Apache 2.0.52

Tags: apache-2.2

I'll start off my saying I'm completely new to Apache!

As part of a site upgrade, I need to disable bwshare, does anyone know where and how I disable that service?

I only have access to Apache by some kind of web-portal...

Answer (score 0):

this is an apache module, so look in your portal under "modules"